# why i need to use init() and cursor() in luci program

Tags: lua, luci

In my cbi files I have:

```
local t=require"luci.model.network".init()
local e=require"luci.model.firewall".init()
local i=require"luci.util"
local e=require"luci.model.uci".cursor()
```

In the above syntax if i remove **init()** and **cursor()** then my program not work properly,need help why it's necessary

From where i can learn about init(),cursor() in luci and why they are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Lua is not an object oriented language that supports constructors / destructors. But it is possible to achieve some similar functionality by defining init / new / whatever name you like to create an object and then operate on that instance. I'd suggest you read tutorials on lua-wiki about module creation and the LuCI source code to learn about what the `init` or `cursor` functions do.